# JS stacktrace error inside kubernates Pod

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am running a reactJs application in Production mode inside a Kubernetes pod.container runtime is docker.
Pod status is Running but  still we don't get UI. Also when I check logs I see the below JS stacktrace error.
To run React application I have given below command

> "build": "set max_old_space_size=8192 && webpack --mode production --max_old_space_size=8192 && serve -s dist -l 3000"

The error I see inside pod logs is

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

<--- Last few GCs --->

```
[114:0x5632d5a724a0]    27622 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 597.8 (600.3) -> 597.3 (600.3) MB, 3.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.185, current mu = 0.145) allocation failure
[114:0x5632d5a724a0]    27627 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 598.1 (600.3) -> 597.5 (600.6) MB, 2.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.185, current mu = 0.145) allocation failure
```

Comment: Please add the PodSpec of the Pod to your question. It looks like you're not giving it sufficient resources.

Comment: resources: 
    limits:
     cpu: 500m
     memory: 1024Mi
    requests:
     cpu: 250m
     memory: 560Mi
I am giving sufficient resources . else pod  would have terminated. But pod is in running state. @YardenShoham

Comment: It's gotta be something with the resources.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `--max_old_space_size` is MB and according to your question you are passing 8192 but your pod is limited in resources to 1024.

You need to do one of the following:

1. Change your pod spec to reserve an amount more than 8192.
2. Change your command to set `--max_old_space_size` to a value under 1024.
3. Or change both, but you need to make sure your pod has enough memory

What happens if you just remove both of the `max_old_space_size` altogether? Do you really need to override this?